# Передача переменных в строке браузера django

Tags: python, django

Делаю поиск на странице с возможностью фильтрация. Надо передать выбранные поля для формирования правильного `queryset`.  Как это лучше сделать? Я создаю переменную `str` в `urls`. Но то делать если надо передать 10 или больше условий фильрации? как организовать динамично передаваемые переменные?

**urls**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', OrdersHomeView.as_view(), name='orders_home'),
    path('filter/<str:tag>', OrdersFilterView.as_view(), name='orders_filter'),
]
```

понимаю, что надо делать через `?=`, как в `php`, но не могу понять как? можно просто обрабатывать строку `str`, но может есть какая-то магия django?

Comment: там flask, а тут django. вопрос в том, что есть какое-то решение в django. как обработать просто str это понятно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так должен выглядеть url в строке браузера: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders_home?message=2`

Фрагмент кода, которым можно доставать параметры, во view: `message = request.GET.get('message')`

`Urls.py` можно оставить без изменений:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('orders_home', views.kek, name='orders_home')
]
```